# website site "show/hide" not working on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

My show/hide tags won't work on mobile devices. It only works on desktop (and if I tick desktop on the mobile device). When I use the chrome dev tools and switch it to mobile I replicate the issue.

This is [my first website](https://leealfred.github.io/LeeCV/), so please be gentle, I am planning on upgrading as I learn so there's no Javascript in these show/hide divs just HTML and CSS.

I'm sure it was working when I first set it up? I've been playing around with "position". I'm not sure if the divs position has anything to do with it? I've played around with:

a) @media but it doesn't seem to help?

b) changing the meta for viewport

c) pulling my hair out

no luck, any help and feedback appreciated :)

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#myStory {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

:checked+#myStory {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
HTML:

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-capable" content="yes" />


    <h2>My Story</h2>
 
  <input type="checkbox" id="story" style="display: none;">

  <div id="myStory" style="margin: auto; text-align: left ">
  
    <p>I was born in the mid 1970's in New Zealand-Aotearoa (in a small city called New Plymouth).

      </div>
  
  <label for="story">Show/hide</label>
```

Comment: On your mobil device? It works in the snippet and desktop and if you select desktop on your phone but not on my phone or on chrome-dev tools when I select any of the phone options?